# Call Method from Differnt Vue Component (file)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to call method from different vue component which resides in different file I've tried with ref and didn't work for me and I know this might be simple but im new to vue please help me to do this task.

Both files reside in same folder

DefinitionManager - need to call method inside this component

```
   methods: {
    closeDrawer() {
      this.drawer = false;
    }
```

DefinitionMaker - I need to call above method by this component method

```
 methods: {
        CallDrawerMethod() {
          Call Method from Definition Manager component
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue best practice for calling a method in a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316490/vue-best-practice-for-calling-a-method-in-a-child-component)

Comment: I tried those answers but no any luck

Answer (score 0):

just add a ref in the child component and call that.

```
<template>
   <div>
     <DefinitionManager ref="definationManager"/>
  </div>
<t/emplate>
<script>
import DefinitionManager from './DefinitionManager.vue'

export default {
  components: {
   DefinitionManager
  },
   methods: {
    CallDrawerMethod() {
      this.$refs.definationManager.closeDrawer();
   }
  }
}
</script>
```