# Using refs with Vue 3 + TypeScript + Options API

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to understand the best way to use refs together with TypeScript and the Options API. [In the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html#template-refs) they reference it like below, but that is without using TS. When it comes to TS, [they only explain how to use it with Composition API.](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-refs)

When I use `this.$refs.myRef` it throws this error `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

I know that I can cast it and use it like this: `(this.$refs.myRef as HTMLElement)` but that I feel shouldn't be necessary to do for every ref every single time.

What is the correct way to use a reference with Options API + TS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a shim like this:

**shims-runtime-core.d.ts**

```js
import * as runtimeCore from '@vue/runtime-core'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $refs: {
      [key: string]: HTMLElement|any,
    },
    // ... more stuff
  }
}
```

And then I can access the refs like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `ref` on a child component to call a trigger function, because using props and a watcher feels to complicated for such a simple thing.

After adding the child component and adding a `ref` in the template

```html
<ChildComponent ref="childComponent"></ChildComponent>
```

I exposed only the trigger function:

```
export default {
    name: "ChildComponent",
    expose: ['someFunction'],  
    methods: {
        someFunction() {
        // …
      },
    },
}
```

See more here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component

Then I tried using it like this in the template

```html
<something v-on:click="($refs.childComponent as typeof ChildComponent).someFunction()"></something>
```

and like this in a method

```
this.$refs.childComponent.someFunction();
```

Even though I got those two errors from volar:
For the use in the template

> error TS18046: '__VLS_ctx.$refs.childComponent' is of type 'unknown'

and for the use in the method

> error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'

So i tried adding type information in both places like this

```
($refs.childComponent as typeof ChildComponent)
```

This doesn't work in the template and you'll get this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'ChildComponent' does not exist on type …

```
<something v-on:click="($refs.childComponent as typeof ChildComponent).someFunction()"></something>
```

#### Solution

But in this method it works fine for some reason

```
methods: {
  callChildMethod() {
    (this.$refs.childComponent as typeof ChildComponent).someFunction();
  },
}
```

So you need to wrap the trigger function in a method, which then is callable in the template

```html
<something v-on:click="callChildMethod()"></something>
```