# Vue $refs Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm simply trying to use `$refs` in my Vue 3 app but I keep getting the Typescript error `Object is of type 'unknown'`. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here's my .vue file:

```
<template>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>
            Add Products
        </h2>
        <Multiselect v-model="products"
                                 mode="tags"
                                 placeholder="Select one or more products..."
                                 ref="multi"
                                 :searchable="true"
                                 :createTag="true"
                                 :options="options"></Multiselect>

        <div v-for="(product, index) in this.products"
                 v-bind:key="index"
                 v-bind:name="product">

            <Button class="primary"
                            text="Remove"
                            @click="removeProduct(product)"></Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Button from '@/components/Button.vue'
import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect'

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'TrackSymptoms',
    components: {
        Button,
        Multiselect
    },
    data () {
        return {
            products: [],
            options: [
                { value: 'Alpha', label: 'Alpha' },
                { value: 'Bravo', label: 'Bravo' },
                { value: 'Charlie', label: 'Charlie' },
                { value: 'Delta', label: 'Delta' }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        removeProduct (product: string) {
            this.$refs.multi.deselect(product)
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

The line `this.$refs.multi.deselect(product)` in the `removeProduct` function is the one producing the error.

This is how it's instructed to be used via the docs:

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.multiselect.open()
}
```

Comment: try out `(this.$refs.multiselect as InstanceType<typeof Multiselect>).open()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what [Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754839/vue-refs-object-is-of-type-unknown#comment118003372_66754839) said, works but it's not recommended, instead, since it looks like everything is using the `products` array, why don't you simply remove the item you want to deselect (remove ?) from it, it should update your MultiSelect and displayed list at the same time.

```html
<div v-for="(product, index) in this.products" :key="index" :name="product">
    <Button class="primary" text="Remove" @click="removeProduct(index)"></Button>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
    /**
     * Remove the product at the specified index
     */
    removeProduct(index: number) {
      this.products.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
```

i'm not sure it's right though, i'm a bit lacking in context to be sure of it, like what does the `deselect()` do

Answer (score 14):

```
 <el-table
        :data="tableData"
        @row-click="rowClicked"
        ref="tableRef"
    >


rowClicked(row: any) {
  (this.$refs['tableRef'] as any).toggleRowExpansion(row);
}
```

force the any type on the object

edit....better solution found by colleague. import relevant type available from search in node_module code of element-plus. In this case the **el-table** has a type:

```
import { ElTable } from 'element-plus';
(this.$refs['tableRef'] as typeof ElTable).toggleRowExpansion(row);
```

Answer (score 6):

Define type for the component you assigned ref to, like below:

```
  (this.$refs.multi as InstanceType<typeof Multiselect>).deselect(product)
```

This should be a better solution than the other answers (no offense).

```
  (this.$refs['tableRef'] as any).toggleRowExpansion(row);
```

coz with my solution you can use IDE'S code completion.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76297364/6411540

```
(this.$refs.childComponent as typeof ChildComponent).someFunction();
```

You can also expose only the needed functionality like this:

```
export default {
  expose: ['publicData', 'publicMethod'],
  data() {
    return {
      publicData: 'foo',
      privateData: 'bar'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    publicMethod() {
      /* ... */
    },
    privateMethod() {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

From the Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component