# How fix Object is of type 'unknown'?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How fix Object is of type 'unknown'?

```
 mounted () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
              this.$refs.task1.classList.add('increase')
            })
```

Comment: I had the same error but in another context, look here for my solution: [SO - Using refs with Vue 3 + TypeScript + Options API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76297364/6411540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the referenced element as follows :

```js
 mounted () {
            this.$nextTick(()=> {
              (this.$refs.task1 as HTMLElement).classList.add('increase')
            })
```