# Calling function inside child component without an event?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently trying to use a method belonging to the parent

```
   <p class="message-date text-center">
       {{ $emit('format_date_day_month_year_time', message.date) }}
   </p>
```

However I am getting the error.

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
```

How can I call a function inside a child component that does not rely on an event? I apologize for asking such a simple question but everything I was able to find on google is using $emit and using an event.

Comment: I did a quick search and found this link [Vue best practice for calling a method in a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316490/vue-best-practice-for-calling-a-method-in-a-child-component).  It recommends a technique that I would recommend as well, passing a prop from parent to child, and watching the prop in the child in order to trigger the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$emit` was designed to only trigger  an event on the current instance of vue. Therefore, it is not possible to receive data from another component this way.

For your case, I would suggest to use [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics) especially if you need to use certain functions among multiple  vue components.

Alternately, let the child component call the  the parent through `$emit` then receive the result  from the parent through a prop.

Your code could be something as follows:

**Child component**

```js
<template>
  <p class="message-date text-center">
    {{ date }}
  </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: {
    date: String,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit("format-date", message.date);
  },
}
</script>
```

**Parent component**

```js
<template>
  <Child :date="childDate" @format-date="formatChildDate" />
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child';

export default {
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  data: () => ({
    childDate: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    formatChildDate(date) {
      this.childDate = this.formatDateDayMonthYearTime(date)
    },
    formatDateDayMonthYearTime(date) {
      //return  the formatted date
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

with $emit you call a function where the Parent can listento.

where you are using it i would suggest a computed prop of the function.

But back to your Question here is a example of emiting and listen.

```
//Parent 
<template>
<MyComponent @childFunction="doSomethingInParent($event)"/>
</template>

//Child
<template>
<button @click="emitStuff">
</template>
.....
methods:{
emitStuff(){
this.$emit(childFunction, somedata)
}
```

with the event you can give Data informations to a Parentcomponent.