# Vue parent component get response from child method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component and a child.
From parent i want to call a method in child component and wait the response. How can i do that?
I need the response for adding a condition in the parent method.

```
<!-- MY CHILD COMPONENT -->
<my-child-component ref="childform" />

// parent method
methods: {
     callChildMethod() {
        this.$refs.childform.onSubmit()
        // if want to get the response and do something
        if (response) {
            //do something
        }
      },
}

//child method
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      //do something
      return false
    },
}
```

Comment: I think that is an anti pattern that you should try to avoid. Communication between parent and child components are done though props[1] and emits[2]. You can watch a prop in the child which calls the function and emits the result. 

[1]: vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html [2]: vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#emits

Comment: If onSubmit method in child component return something, then you can simply achieve this by assigning it in a variable `const response = this.$refs.childform.onSubmit()` and then you can check `if (response) { ... }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue best practice for calling a method in a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316490/vue-best-practice-for-calling-a-method-in-a-child-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem could be solved using refs and it works as follows:
In parent component:

```
 <parent @click="clickHandler">
    <child ref="child" />
 </parent>
```

In your parent script tag:

```
methods: {
   async clickHandler(){
      //call child component's method using reference given in parent component
         await this.$refs.child.child_method_name();
      // rest of your parent code here
   }
}
```