# How to declare ref for a generic component in Vue with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, typescript-generics

I have a generic component with generic props using [this feature in Vue](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#generics). I exposed a function from it and I want to call the function from the outside using [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317353/11225486). However, I don't know how to write the type of ref. Here is the minimal code for this problem:

TestGenericComp.vue:

```js
<template></template>
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
    defineProps<{
        data: T;
    }>();
    function func(obj: T) {
        console.log(`Hello ${obj}`);
    }
    defineExpose({ func });
</script>
```

About.vue:

```js
<template>
    <test-generic-comp :data="''" ref="comp"></test-generic-comp>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestGenericComp from '../components/TestGenericComp.vue';
const comp = ref<???>(); // How to write this type so func can be called
comp.value.func("Hi");
</script>
```

From [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-template-refs) it states that I should use `ref<InstanceType<typeof TestGenericComp>>`, but they won't work since they are generic, making error:

```
Type '<T>(__VLS_props: { data: T; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, __VLS_ctx?: Pick<{ props: { data: T; }; expose(exposed: { ...; }): void; attrs: any; slots: {}; emit: any; }, "attrs" | ... 1 more ... | "slots"> | undefined, __VLS_setup?: { props: { data: T; }; expose(exposed: { ...; }): voi...'
 does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.
Type '<T>(__VLS_props: { data: T; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, __VLS_ctx?: Pick<{ props: { data: T; }; expose(exposed: { ...; }): void; attrs: any; slots: {}; emit: any; }, "attrs" | ... 1 more ... | "slots"> | undefined, __VLS_setup?: { ...; }) => VNode<...> & { ...; }' 
 provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.
```

using `ref<typeof TestGenericComp>` is accepted, but `comp.value!.func();` emits error:

```
Property 'func' does not exist on type '<T>(__VLS_props: { data: T; } & VNodeProps & 
AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, __VLS_ctx?: Pick<{ props: { data: T; }; 
expose(exposed: { ...; }): void; attrs: any; slots: {}; emit: any; }, 
"attrs" | ... 1 more ... | "slots"> | undefined, 
__VLS_setup?: { ...; }) => VNode<...> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)
```

**Edit**

Apparently, leaving the type empty (using `ref()` directly) works, but its type would be any. How can I annotate its type?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open issue on the Vue core github https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/8373

The issue is the `defineExpose()` not contributing to the type properly.

A partial workaround is to use `ReturnType<>` instead of `InstanceType<>`. However, this will still give you a type error claiming the exposed values don't exist.

My solution was to simply extend the ReturnType with the functions defined. In my case it looked like this (my expose was a `reset()` function).

```js
const form = ref<(ReturnType<typeof DynamicForm> & { reset: () => void }) | null>(null)
```

In your case, it might be slightly more difficult since your function takes a generic argument. However, since the parent knows the value of the prop being passed, it would reason that it would be able to explicitly type your exposed function's argument.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const data: Data = {}

const comp = ref<(ReturnType<typeof TestGenericComp> & { func: (obj: Data) => void }) | null>(null)
</script>

<template>
  <TestGenericComp :data="data" ref="comp" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution but works:

```
export type UnwrapRefDict<T extends Record<string, Ref<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Ref<infer V> ? V : T[P]
}

export type GenericComponentInstanceType<T extends (...args: any[]) => { __ctx?: { expose(exposed: any): any } }>
    = UnwrapRefDict<ArgumentsType<Exclude<ReturnType<T>['__ctx'], undefined>['expose']>['0']>

// usage

const comp = ref<GenericComponentInstanceType<typeof TestGenericComp<T /* real type here */>>>()
```