# Calling a method from another component via <script setup>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar, vue-script-setup

I'd like to call a component's method inside another component in vue3. As I'm using the  mode, I cant say 'export const myFunction = () => {letsFunction}'. I tried using defineExpose and provide/inject but the function arrives in the destination component as an object of type any and not as function.

```
// component of origin:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { EventClickArg, Plugin } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { useApiStore } from '../stores/apiStore'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

const store = useApiStore()
const projects = store.projects
console.log(projects)
const setProjectDataAsEvents = () => {
  options.events = projects.map((project) => ({
    title: project.name,
    extendedProps: { resources: project.resources?.map(resource => `${resource.surname} ${' '} ${resource.lastname}`) },
    start: project.startDate,
    end: project.endDate,
    allDay: true,
    backgroundColor: project.colour,
    textColor: '#000000',
    borderColor: project.colour
  }))
}
onMounted(() => setProjectDataAsEvents())
const options = {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin] as Plugin[],
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev, today, next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridWeek, dayGridMonth, dayGridYear'
  },
  weekends: true,
  events: [] as { title: string; start: Date; end: Date; allDay: boolean }[],
  eventClick: function (info: EventClickArg) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: info.event.title,
      html: `
        <div>
          <strong>Zeitraum:</strong> <br/>${info.event.start?.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })} - ${info.event.end?.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })}
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>Resourcen:</strong><br>${info.event.extendedProps.resources?.join('<br>')}
        </div>
      `,
      icon: 'info',
      toast: true,
      background: info.event.backgroundColor,
      confirmButtonColor: '#536363',
      iconColor: '#536363',
      showCloseButton: true,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  }
}
</script>

// destination component Where I need to call the method

import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useApiStore } from './apiStore'

export const useSetupStore = defineStore('setup', () => {
  const apiStore = useApiStore()
  async function initialize () {
    console.log('%cInitializing setup store..', 'color:limegreen')
    apiStore.fetchData()
    // I want to call the method here
  }
  return {
    initialize
  }
})
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This was already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316490/vue-best-practice-for-calling-a-method-in-a-child-component/75145481#75145481